# html "&" and parameters

Tags: python, html, api, python-2.7

I am passing several parameters through the echonest api using urllib2 in Python.  some artist and track names have the ampersand (`&`) character.

example:
Tommy James & The Shondells == `artist=Tommy%20James%20&20The%20Shondells`

How can I pass the ampersand character through the api parameter correctly?

full api query:

`http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=KEY_GOES_HERE&artist=Tommy%20James%20&20The%20Shondells&title=Crimson%20and%20Clover`

Comment: How are you encoding the parameters now? You'd normally use `urllib.quote` to handle encoding, and it'll encode `&` correctly for you.

Comment: Have you simply tried `%26`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't state how you are building your query string, but I urge you to check out the [`urllib.quote()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote%28%29), [`urllib.quote_plus()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus%28%29) and [`urllib.urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) functions instead of manually encoding anything. The latter will apply `quote_plus()` to the keys and values you pass in:

```
>>> from urllib import urlencode
>>> artist = 'Tommy James & The Shondells'
>>> api_key = 'KEY_GOES_HERE'
>>> urlencode({'artist': artist, 'api_key': api_key})
'api_key=KEY_GOES_HERE&artist=Tommy+James+%26+The+Shondells'
```

Now your `artist` entry has been encoded using `+` for spaces and `%26` for the ampersand.

Comment: all great resources, thank you.  I am iterating over a csv file I've created and pulling values from each cell.

Answer (score 1):

Before you add your artist variable to the url, first try replacing each occurrence of '&' with its corresponding uri encoding, '%26'.

```
artist = artist.replace('&', '%26')
```

Comment: Instead of manually replacing any such characters, you should use `urllib.quote()` instead. What if there are `=` characters in a name? Or `/`?

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for, was not aware of the .quote() method.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mike: There are more function in that library that you may need to look at. The [`urlencode()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) for example, which url quotes keys and values for you.